# Stress test uploading speed of the server

Tags: network-speed, stress-testing

I need to test a server max uploading speed, before production. What options do i have?

Any services, tips, tricks are welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing about brandwidth stress testing or did i missed something?

Comment: What possibilities have you researched or tried leading you to your question?

Comment: Good question - but a [duplicate](http://serverfault.com/q/54870/169426) I think.

Comment: Speedtest can't affort such testing capability, which i need. It's showing 70mbit/sec uploading speed, but it's should be over 300mbit/sec.

Answer (score 0):

[Speedtest.net Mini](http://www.speedtest.net/mini.php) looks pretty good.

I tried the demo at the link above, and it looks pretty straightforward to install on your own server for download and upload metrics.  As the linked page says "the only requirement is that your web server supports PHP, ASP.NET, ASP or JSP".

Answer (score 0):

I normally use iperf on a VPS host